# Sync Problems when transferring a PT10 session to a PT9 session

Tags: sync, pro-tools-10, pro-tools-9

Hello All,

An issue came up recently where a PT10 project was saved as a PT9 project so that we could work on a system that only had PT9 on it. The issue was that some of the clips were out of sync but these sync problems were random and only about 30% of the clips had these sync issues. I was told that this could happen if you do a real time save on PT10 and then save as a PT9 project.

Have any of you had issues regarding this problem and if so, what did you do to resolve these issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since Pro Tools 10 can handle multiple file formats in a single session, is the issue possibly that the Pro Tools 9 session is referencing multiple sample rates?

Comment: Yews, that is possible even though the sessions are set to 48k. Many of the SFX we have from licensed libraries are 44.1 so that might be an issue. 